# Get correct date from timestamp at a timezone

Tags: sql-server, date, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a (Azure) SQL Server database with timestamps in UTC. I want to get the date at a specific timezone.

The following shows the issue

```
DECLARE @TS DateTime2='2020-02-08 23:00:00'

SELECT CAST((@TS at time zone 'W. Europe Standard Time') as date) as StartDate, @TS as StartTimeStampUTC, @TS at time zone 'W. Europe Standard Time' as StartTimeStampLocalTime
```

StartTimeStampUTC : 2020-02-08 23:00:00.0000000
StartTimeStampLocalTime : 2020-02-08 23:00:00.0000000 +01:00
StartDate : 2020-02-08

I would have expected the StartDate value to be 2020-02-09, as local time is 2020-02-08 23:00 + 01:00 = 2020-02-09 00:00

How can I get the correct date?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below-mentioned process in SQL Server. 
 1. Get UTC time using  - GETUTCDATE()
 2. Get difference between your DateTime and UTC DateTime using below link - 
     https://dzone.com/articles/dates-and-times-in-sql-server-at-time-zone
 3. Add that difference in UTC DateTime

Please find below script -
SELECT  GETDATE() AS 'Local Timezone',
        GETUTCDATE() AS 'Utc_Timezone',
        (DATEADD(HOUR,5,DATEADD(MINUTE,30,GETUTCDATE()))) as'Local Timezone based on UTC'

I have added 5:30 Hrs based on my local timeZone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick :

```
SELECT CAST(dateadd(hour,DATEdiff(hour,@TS AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time',@TS ),@TS) as date) as StartDate
```

answer is now 2020-02-09 as expected

Comment: use two consecutive at time zone: the first to set the datetime at utc (because you store at utc) and the second to calculate the datetime at eu. st. Then get the date from the final result: select cast(cast('2020-02-08 23:00:00.0000000' as datetime2) at time zone 'UTC'  at time zone 'W. Europe Standard Time' as date)